# is it possible to call 2 seperate function onClick event in asp:checkbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an checkbox control in my asp.net application: and currently I have a function that gets called with the onClick event

So it looks like this....

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkResOther" runat="server" 
onclick="RadioControl(this);" Text="Other" />
```

The `RadioControl(this)` function basically checks that only one of 5 checkboxes is checked in.

So the way this checkbox is utilized, is that I have 5 checkboxes, 4 of them are normal options, the 5th one "chkResOther" when checked in is supposed to enable a textbox, so that a text value can be entered. On page load, the textbox is disabled, and basically my goal is when checkbox is checked in, run the RadioControl(this) function, as well as a function to enabled the textbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not call RadioControl and the other function from another function, then attack the third function as the handler?

Comment: yeah that's true, I will actually call another function from RadioControl since this function is only used with those 5 checkboxes - too early for me to think. I just wandered if there's a way to basically call 2 function from the onClick: event

Comment: S's James' answer shows, it is possible to literally call both inline in the `oncall` callback. Having inline code like that isn't preferred though. If you ever need to call these exact 2 functions together again as handlers, you'll need to manually write both function. Then, if you need to make changes to what you call, or add another handler, you'll need to go around and change all the `onclick` strings. If you just group them under a function though, that's not a problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkResOther" runat="server" onclick="RadioControl(this); otherFunction();" Text="Other" />
```

Hope that helps! :)

+1 if it did? Trying to get 15 rep! lol

Comment: Haha yeah i always give +1 - regardless of whether response is correct or not, simply for the EFFORT. You good sir deserve +1

Comment: Thank you! :) I've been struggling getting +1's

Answer (score 1):

Just call both from a third function:

```
function RadioControl(cb) {
}

function OtherTextboxFunc(cb) {
}

function Handler(cb) {
    RadioControl(cb);
    OtherTextboxFunc(cb)
}

... onclick="Handler(this);"
```